# Do I need to beat Lynx to get Level 7 Gear?

Tags: shadow-fight-2

Do I have to defeat Lynx to get Level 7 weapons and armor? I am very confused about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This wiki page](https://shadowfight.fandom.com/wiki/Lynx_(SF2)) states:

> Player can obtain Lynx's Claws by defeating him once more in Eclipse mode. It can be obtained at any level, as early as level 7 to level 52.

That means you have to reach level 7 to obtain Lynx's Claws.

Comment: I am still confuse do I or do I not have to beat Lynx to get Level 7 weapons and Gear?

Comment: I think you don't have to beat Lynx, but you should be at least level 7 if you want to obtain Lynx's Claws.